# meaning of these lines of code

Tags: vba

I am converting Visual Basic 6.0 code to .NET 4.5. I have the following lines of code. Can you tell me what they mean?

```
SQLMappingTables = " SELECT * FROM MappingTables " & _
                    " WHERE  Group_Level = ? " & _
                    "    AND Group_Code  = ? " & _
                    "    AND Code = ? " 
Set Cmd_MappingTables = New ADODB.Command
Cmd_MappingTables.CommandText = SQLMappingTables
Cmd_MappingTables.CommandType = adCmdText
/// These are the line I do not understand
Set DefGroup_Level = Cmd_MappingTables.CreateParameter(, adChar, adParamInput, 1)
Set DefGroup_Code = Cmd_MappingTables.CreateParameter(, adChar, adParamInput, 15)
Set DefCode8 = Cmd_MappingTables.CreateParameter(, adChar, adParamInput, 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It defines three unnamed (first parameter left out) string (adChar) input parameters (adParamInput) of length 1, 15 and 3.

You can find a [description here](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_comm_createparameter.asp).

I would expect the subsequent lines to assign values to the input parameters, before the command is executed.

Comment: Lindback Thanks for your quick response  so if i pass value in SQLMappingTables what will the result as example is there `Group_Level = adchar, Group_Code= adParamInput, Code = 15 `

Comment: Look for code that assigns values to `DefGroup_Level`, `DefGroup_Code` and `DefCode8`. Those are the search parameters that correspond to the three `?` in the `SELECT` statement. The assignment of the search values is not included in the code you posted in the question.